# React/Redux Connect issues with ownProps / typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

When redux connect has been called along with options but without OwnProps it causes typescript issues regarding the built in props like ref. So if I try:

Parent component:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  private placeholder: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    <MyComponent ref={(e: any) => { this.placeholder = e; }} />
  }
}
```

My component:

```
import { doSomethingAction } from 'actions';

interface State { something?: string; }
interface StateProps { someProp: string; }
interface DispachProps { doSomething: () => void }
type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps;

class MyComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state: State = { someProp: false };
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>this.props.someProp</div>);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: Store): StateProps {
  return {
    someProp: state.somePropState
  }
}

function mapDispachToProps(dispach): DispachProps {
  return {
    doSomething: () => dispach(doSomethingAction())
  }
}

// same issue even if third type for OwnProps is added
export default connect<StateProps, DispachProps> (
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispachToProps,
  null,
  { forwardRef: true }
)(MyComponent)
```

I get following typescript error for MyComponent:

Type '{ ref: (e: any) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly>': someProp, doSomething.

Suddenly it treats all of those properties as required own properties. It will produce same error even in case if third type for OwnProps is regularly added. Is that a bug or am I missing something. If it is a bug then is there any elegant way of overcoming this until it is fixed (I know I can add third type for OwnProps as any but don't think its so nice solution) ?
(react 16.8.0, react-redux 6.0.0, @types/react  16.8.2, @types/react-redux 7.0.1)

Comment: One thing is the lack of curly braces around `{ this.placeholder = e.getWrappedInstance() }`. It would also help if you shared all relevant code (`MyComponent` and the component in which it's rendered).

Comment: @KarolMajewski thanks for pointing out but it was just to preview general case. I've added more complete example now. So event in case where third type is defined for OwnProps in MyComponent same typescript error occurs in this case when options are specified. If options and third param are omitted error is gone.

Comment: I guess it is typing issue with InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps which always mixes all of the props if all four attributes of connect call are provided. I could overcome it by exporting as ConnectedComponentClass<typeof MyComponent, {}>